# When I click in a image, put this image in background of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click in an IMG, I want to set this image as a background of a div, I tried the code below but it didn't work, can somebody help me??

**HTML:**

```
<div id="conteudo">
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function clickImagem2(){
   document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background="url('images/JO1.jpg') no-
repeat";
}
```

Comment: Where is the `click` part?

Comment: As @Dekel mentioned, here's what he means. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: Either you are doing something wrong in the click event or the image url isn't correct. Also, it will be better if you create a css class with that `background` statement and append only the class to the element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830062/how-to-change-img-src-with-a-transition-by-clicking-another-image/43830345#43830345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here onClick event we pass the src attribute of the clicked image then it set as background image in that function.

```js
function clickImagem2(src){
   document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background="url('"+src+"') no-repeat";
}

clickImagem2();
```

```html
<img onClick="clickImagem2(this.src)" width="50" height="50" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUb9_jxtyBNrEPTWHDDq9FMbEiRaCot2uesclTBSs9e0sgdjCUzAsYF7Y">

<img onClick="clickImagem2(this.src)" width="50" height="50" src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg">

<div style="width:120px;height:120px" id="conteudo">
Clicke image will display here
</div>
```

Comment: Is this is the expected output?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i'm new on this site

Comment: Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Add click event and on click event set style.

I add snippet please see that.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>getElementById example</title>
</head>
  <script>
  function changeImage(src) {  
  var elem = document.getElementById('para');   
  elem.style.backgroundImage = "url("+src+")"; 
  }
  </script>
<body>
  <div id="para" style="height:100px">Some text here</div>
  <button onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/100x100');">clickme</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17331601)

Comment: @RootIngenious Sorry for that. Now I add example also.Is it Ok?

Comment: It's almost it, but I don't want change color of background of the Div, I wish put a IMG on div, thanks at all

Comment: @Sora code updated..Please check you need to just pass image url in click event and it's done. thanks...:)

Comment: @D.V , Perfect . .  :-)

Comment: @RootIngenious Thanks..:)(y)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use "onclick"  method to call clickImagem2() function.

see the following example for guidance

```js
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the call of the function. Adding **onclick** to your div can call your function.

**See this working fiddle:**

```js
function clickImagem2(){
   document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background="url('http://placehold.it/100x100') no-repeat";
}
```

```css
#conteudo{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo" onclick="clickImagem2()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on an image, the event contains the clicked element. From here you can get the `src` and use this as the background image of your `div`.

```js
const
  background = document.getElementById('background');
  
function onClickHandler(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('preview')) {
    return;
  }

  background.style.backgroundImage = `url(${event.target.src})`;
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
```

```css
.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: .2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}
.previews {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.preview {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
}

.preview + .preview {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" class="background"></div>
<div class="previews">
  <img class="preview" src="//lorempixel.com/320/200/cats/1"/>
  <img class="preview" src="//lorempixel.com/320/200/cats/2"/>
  <img class="preview" src="//lorempixel.com/320/200/cats/3"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `bind` a `click` event handler, using `addEventListener` method.

```js
document.getElementById('myImage').addEventListener('click',clickImagem2,false);
function clickImagem2(){
   let image=document.getElementById('myImage');
   document.getElementById('conteudo').style.backgroundImage="url('"+image.src+"')";
}
```

```css
img{
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
}
div{
   height: auto;
   left: 0;
   margin: 0;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 674px;
   padding: 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" id="myImage">
<div id="conteudo">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks !! I'll try it !!